# LoadSceneAsync fails to switch scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

I am trying to use `LoadSceneAsync()` in Unity, but all it does is leave me hanging, forcing me to end Unity before I can try again.
Because of the previously mentioned restarting, I have not tried much.

`Fade.cs`:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Fade : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Object;

    private IEnumerator IFadeObjectIn(string scene) {
        const float Seconds = 1.5f;

        Object.SetActive(true);
        Object.GetComponent<Graphic>().CrossFadeAlpha(0f,0f,false);
        Object.GetComponent<Graphic>().CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, Seconds, false);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Seconds);

        SceneLoader.LoadScene(scene);
    }

    public void FadeObjectIn(string scene) {
        StartCoroutine(IFadeObjectIn(scene));
    }

}
```

`SceneLoader.cs`:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour {
    public static string SceneName = "Game";

    public static void LoadScene(string Name) {
        SceneName = Name;
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Load");
    }
}

I am not getting any errors.
```

Comment: Refer to the example https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html

Comment: ....How is this supposed to solve my problem? Please be more specific about what part of the example i need to refer to.

Comment: Well the fact you don’t follow the sample which shows how to use asynchronous scene loading as you never change the scene

Comment: @BugFinder the Coroutine is only required if you want to do something meanwhile like a progress bar etc .. it is not required for the scene to switch ... calling `LoadSceneAsync` should be enough to switch the scene. I don't see a problem in the code actually..

Comment: @AteurGames do you get any errors? Is the scene name correct? Is the scene added to the build settings?

Comment: @derHugo I have not gotten any errors as far as I know. Also, trying to load the scene via the Unity editor itself freezes.

Comment: Are you sure it is the scene loading freezing your app and not something else? Could you try `SceneManager.LoadScene` instead just to see if this works? Be aware that you harcoded `"Load"` for the scene to be loaded .. you ignore the passed string value. It is very unlikely that a build in Unity method would freeze the editor entirely... The behaviour you describe rather sounds like there is an endless loop somewhere else in your app!

Comment: @derHugo I will try that when I get the chance.